# fo-block padding with negative value create issue

Tags: xslt, padding, dita

While using negative values for padding top in xsl fo-block, the block padding is adjusted but there is a space created on the bottom of the page. Even there is space in first page, some content goes to next page. Please help to resolve this issue

Comment: Show us your relevant XSL-FO file.

Comment: Which FO formatter are you using?